phantom email recipient for profile notification?
strange issue.  I have a profile that sends an email notification when it is submitted.  The addresses for the email notification have been updated, but the profile notification is still being sent to the deleted addresses.  I can't for the life of me figure out where those recipient addresses is coming from!
I've searched the database, and checked all the other profiles' settings to verify this mail isn't being sent by some other profile. Is there someplace these notification mail addresses are cached?
Joomla 3.10, CiviCRM 5.63

Update: from what I can tell, it seems although the new email addresses are being saved in the "Notify when profile form is submitted?" profile field, the notifications are actually being sent to the previously entered addresses??

if you have logging on and if you have access to the db, then the table that should record that change is log_civicrm_uf_group - if you know the profile id then you can filter that table to show the changes. sounds odd. assume you have already cleared caches.
if this is not where the data is, then other option would be civirules.

Thanks for your response Pete, based on your suggestions I had a look at the log_civicrm_uf_group table and LO AND BEHOLD found a different problem completely -- the admin (backend) and component (frontend) civicrm.settings.php were pointing to two different databases!  So the backend accepted the change/displayed it correctly in the profile, but when the profile was submitted the values from the OTHER database were used to package up the emails.  (Also the submitted data is being entered in the wrong database, which is another problem I'm very glad to have solved!)

Thanks SO MUCH for pointing me the right direction.

glad you got that sorted
